# Postgres Upgrade Heroku from 9.2.4 to 9.3

Tags: postgresql, heroku

I am fairly new to Rails and especially [Heroku](https://www.heroku.com). I received an email informing me that I needed to update my PostgreSQL DB version. I am a little fuzzy on how to accomplish this without changing my plan. I am currently using Heroku's [Kappa Postgres plan](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-postgres-legacy-plans). Based on what I am reading here:

https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/upgrade-heroku-postgres-with-pgbackups

Should I use the command:

`heroku addons:add heroku-postgresql:kappa --version 9.3`

And then just continue on as instructed?

Answer (score 0):

Just doing this myself, from 9.2.4 databases ...

You don't have to upgrade to 9.3, you can just create a new 9.2 and it will be 9.2.6, in which the issue you're being notified about has been fixed. However if you go to 9.3 the plans are different -- https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-postgres-plans#standard-tier

It's more simple/safe to upgrade with a follower database. Instructions here, although you probably want to add your app name to most of those commands. https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-postgres-follower-databases#database-upgrades-and-migrations-with-changeovers

Comment: I see.  So I should just simply be able to use followers instead of using pg:backup and such?

Comment: Yes, if you're on a tier that supports it. On the other hand, I think that if you just wait until Monday then Heroku will run the upgrade for you.